# angularJS and symfony restful web application

Tags: angularjs, symfony

I am developping a Restful web application with angularJS (frontend) and symfony2 (backend),I want to add statistics(BI) to my project,in your opinion which laguage is the best for this kind of applications,bundels of symfony2,libraries of PHP5 or javacript (JQUERY) 
my second question is,what are the advantages of creating your Symfony API separetly from the client application(AngularJS)(if I want to add a mobile extension of my applciation)
thanks for help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's mainly a design choice to increase separation of concerns in your app :

- Your symfony application will only serve data (in JSON, or XML, or any other data representation) and has nothing to know about how your views are rendered to make his job.
- In the other hand, your Angular App will only be concerned about views and user interaction.

It's a good choice, if you want many different clients to call your API : for example, a Mobile App can call your API as your Angular App. In this case, when you call the API with your mobile App, you doesn't want symfony returns HTML templates and other stuffs specifics to web development.

FYI, there are awesome plugin to transform your symfony 2 app into a RESTful application, like [FOSRestBundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle).

**Edit :**

About your statistics : which kind of statistics do you need to store ?

**Edit 2 :**

As your statistics are about data (and not directly user actions), you need to make an entrypoint in your REST app to return data (e.g. number of orders, total amount of all orders). After that, it's AngularJS which will manage rendering of the charts with the data coming from symfony.

Comment: Hi @Elorfin thanks for your reply ^_^ in facts,my application is a busniss web applicatio,statistics concern the charge of orders or progress in sales or buy rates (pie charts,bar chart or line graph)

Comment: if I choose to use phonegap as my mobile application,is this a good solution,and every echange with symfony will be done with ajax

Comment: @miratum: I don't know exactly how work phonegap. So if you want more information about it post a new question with a phonegap tag. Someone with more experience in phonegap will can help you. I can't on this point. For your stats, I have edited my answer.